# Android Bluetooth - How to initiate Pairing

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to initiate a pairing request (not connection at this point of time) to a non android device. This can be found working on Settings Application > Network > Bluetooth Settings > Click on a device after scan. A pop up appears on both the devices with a 6 digit pin.

As per Android's documentation this should have popped up in my application as well, if I do something like this

```
device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
```

As per Android's API documentation

> "Once a connection is made with a
>   remote device for the first time, a
>   pairing request is automatically
>   presented to the user."

And it is also mentioned that

> "The current Android Bluetooth API's
>   require devices to be paired before an
>   RFCOMM connection can be established.
>   (Pairing is automatically performed
>   when you initiate an encrypted
>   connection with the Bluetooth APIs.)"

Even when I used the sample Bluetooth Chat application (only to test if it initiates a pairing on first connection) it didn't worked.

I also tried using a generic UDID like "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB" but to no avail.

Couldn't find the source code of Settings Application (Android OS 2.1) to figure out myself. The sources available in Android GIT were for Android 2.3

**Even if you cannot answer the question, only pointing out to Android Packages Settings App sources for Android 2.1 might do the trick for me.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works for me with this UUID : "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB".
The intent for pairing request is launched when you call socket.connect() if I remember correctly.

Comment: It worked for me finally when I deleted the app and removed pairing from both devices (which I manually created earlier). Didn't knew what was faulty, may be I was trying too many things to make it work.

Comment: @roly Just out of curiosity: Where is that UUID coming from?

Comment: @Zainodis It's quoted on d.android.com here: [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(java.util.UUID))(As hint)