# How to check a Bluetooth remote device has been connected with a different phone in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

My android application has to connect to a remote Bluetooth  device whose Bluetooth address is known to the app. The application will not be able to connect to the device if it is already connected with a different phone as the remote device can accept connection from a single phone at atime. In such cases, the app has to display an alert of "device is already paired with a different phone". My question is how the app can detect whether the remote device is already connected to a different phone ? I know BluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery() can be used to check whether the device is discoverable. But I am not using this as the app knows the bluetooth address of the device, also I don't want to use it as it is a time consuming process. So is there an alternative method to detect it?

Comment: Is there any way to follow this question? I've almost the same problem. Anyway, @Sinu Varghese can you please look at my question too? May be you can help me with this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35239880/detect-all-bluetooth-devices-headsets-phones-etc-nearby-without-forcing-the