# Android Bluetooth cannot discover nearby devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I am making a Android application that needs to connect with a Bluetooth device. I followed the documentation from android developers but it seems that onReceive() function in the bluetoothReceiver is never getting called. Like no devices are found.

**Permissions**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

onCreate() of Main Activity

```
bluetoothConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        enableBluetooth();
    }
});
```

**enableBluetooth() - used to start bluetooth**

```
private void enableBluetooth() {
    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    //Bluetooth not supported on device
    if(bluetoothAdapter == null){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device Not Supporting Bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    //Bluetooth not enabled
    if(!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
        //Open setting to enable bluetooth
        Intent enableBluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }
}
```

**discoverBluetooth() - add to list discovered Bluetooth device and also print to logcat**

```
  private void discoverBluetooth() {
         bluetoothReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                Log.d("Device action: ", action);
                if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
                    BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    String discoveredDeviceName = device.getName() + " " + device.getAddress();
                    bluetoothList.add(discoveredDeviceName);

                    Log.d("Device: ", discoveredDeviceName);
                }
            }
        };

    }
```

**onActivityResult() - If user starts bluetooth call startDiscovery() and call above function discoverBluetooth()**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth Connected" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Register the BroadcastReceiver

            discoverBluetooth();
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
            registerReceiver(bluetoothReceiver, filter); // Don't forget to unregister during onDestroy
            boolean isStarted = bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth Discovery status:" + (isStarted? " Started" : " Not Started"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth Not Connected" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**onStop()**

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(bluetoothReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();

}
```

Comment: You can refer to this project on Github, it's a google samples project for developing BLE on android:
https://github.com/Fakher-Hakim/android-BluetoothLeGatt

Comment: will I be able to discover other phones?

Comment: Your bluetooth devices need to be discoverable. Yes you can find nearby phones when the bluetooth is turned on. I have written my findings about bluetooth discovery here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36984988/3145960

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add the Bluetooth related permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED"/>
```