# Properly implementing bluetooth discovery

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm trying to write code for an android app that uses Bluetooth. I can access the devices I've already paired with just fine but I am unable to discover new devices. I've looked on stack overflow but there doesn't seem to be an answer directly for me. Here is the `.java`, `.xml`, and what it looks like.

```
public class Discover extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<connectableDevices> found = new ArrayList<connectableDevices>(); // appendable name array

    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(); // BT adapter

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_discover);

        if(mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }

        mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Locating nearby devices...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


        BTAdapter BTadapter = new BTAdapter(this, found);

        ListView deviceList2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.discoverList);

        deviceList2.setAdapter(BTadapter);
    }


    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Discovery has found a device. Get the BluetoothDevice
                // object and its info from the Intent.
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                String deviceName = device.getName();
                String deviceHardwareAddress = device.getAddress(); // MAC address
                found.add(new connectableDevices(deviceName, deviceHardwareAddress));
                //MAC.add(deviceHardwareAddress);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        //...

        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        // Don't forget to unregister the ACTION_FOUND receiver.
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }
}
```

And the layout is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.rperdomo.btaccelerometerdata.Discover">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="274dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:text="Found Devices"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/discoverList"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/discoverList"
            android:layout_width="395dp"
            android:layout_height="454dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**App output**

[image]

Comment: Can you share your `AndroidMenifest.xml` file?

Comment: This is in there if that why you asked.

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to discover new devices, because the devices are not discoverable. You need to put the devices those you are looking for in a discoverable mode and then you will see those devices in your android application. Please check the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35239880/3145960) that was asked by me few years back.

However, it is not possible to detect nearby bluetooth devices without having them in discoverable mode. Please see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36984988/3145960) below the question as well.

Comment: So you're saying that code looks correct then? I do have devices im testing with.

Answer (score 0):

A location permission is required because Bluetooth scans can be used to gather information about the location of the user. Put **these** permission in your `AndroidMenifest.xml` file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: I added the permissions but the output is still the same. Could it be something else?

Comment: try to put `startDiscovery` after `registerreceiver`. This may be the case. Also make sure your bluetooth is on.

Comment: Sadly that didnt change anything

Comment: Write `@Override` just above `onReceive` function.

Comment: I finally got it working. Turns out the list-adapter pairing lines shouldve gone inside the broadcast reciever, and since im running android 7.0 i had to ask permission to use location.