# Is it possible to detect nearby Bluetooth-enable smartphones and nearby Beacons at the same time?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-bluetooth, altbeacon, android-ibeacon

I am developing an android app that able to detect nearby bluetooth-opened smartphone and nearby Beacons at the same time, I successfully detected nearby Beacons using android-beacon-library, when I am trying to detect bluetooth-opened devices, I am not able to do that:

- android-beacon-library runs in `Thread 1` to discovery beacon information and it works perfects.
- I was wrote Bluetooth discovery service using traditional `Bluetooth discovery` methods that runs in `Thread 2`.
- I am trying to start those two service that runs in different thread at the same time.

**Result**
The result it that `Thread 1` will run first and last for less than `30 seconds` and then `Thread 2` will run, in the following times, `Thread 2` will run all the time, while `Thread 1` not run at all.

Is it because that smartphone only able to deal with one Bluetooth operation? meaning that you cannot detect traditional bluetooth devices and iBeacon at the same time?

Comment: You might find this post helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35239880/detect-all-bluetooth-devices-headsets-phones-etc-nearby-without-forcing-the

Comment: You can certainly make this work. Understand that a phone must be advertising for you to detect it.  Please post your code so we can help find the issue.